# How to display the value in a readonly input field in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, database, postgresql

So, in my project, a user needs to register first before logging-in. I am trying to display their first, middle and last name. But, I am having a problem since multiple data are displayed on my input field. What is the correct query? Here is my controller code

```
     public function get_first_name()
{
    $first_names = UserModel::all();
    $input="<input></input>";
    foreach($first_names as $first_name)
    {
        $input.="<input value={$first_name->seq_id}>{$first_name->first_name}</input>";
    }
    return $input;
}

    public function step1()
{
    $users = UserModel::all();
    $data['optStatus']=$this->get_civil_status();
    $data['displayFirstName']=$this->get_first_name();
    return view ("enrollment-steps.step1", $data);
}
```

Here is the blade file

```html
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">First 
       Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id='firstName' readonly value="{!! $displayFirstName !!}" >
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

[this is the data that it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOfba.png)

Comment: If the user has not registered yet, where are you getting there name from? Please explain that and I can help more.

Comment: i have a middleware. only the registered users can access the step1

Comment: Is the step1 on your project the personal information of a specific user or a multiple user ?

Comment: for multiple users, its like a student application website.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusing stuff going on there, but you probably want

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id='firstName' readonly value="{{ $data['displayFirstName'] }}" >
```

which will display the value with the key 'displayFirstName' in the `$data` array.

`dd` is your friend, use this in your blade file to see what you have in your $data variable.

```
{{dd($data)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you controller bind the data's in a single variable, then show it in the blade

```
public function get_first_name()
    {
        $first_names = UserModel::all();
        $input="<input></input>";
        foreach($first_names as $first_name)
        {
            $input.="<input value={$first_name->seq_id}>{$first_name->first_name}</input>";
        }
        return $input;
    }
```

Instead of this, do something like this:

```
public function get_first_name()
    {
        $first_names = UserModel::all();
        $input="<input></input>";
        foreach($first_names as $first_name)
        {
            $displayname = $first_name->seq_id . $first_name->first_name;
            $input.="<input value="{$displayname}"</input>";
        }
        return $input;
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code, and it is the nearest answer to my question, i just modified it a little bit.